# python 3.3 basic error

Tags: python-3.3

I have python 3.3 installed.
i use the example they use on their site:

```
import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://python.org/')
html = response.read()
```

the only thing that happens when I run it is I get this :

```
======RESTART=========
```

I know I am a rookie but I figured the example from python's own website should be able to work.
It doesn't. What am I doing wrong?Eventually I want to run this script from the website below. But I think urllib is not going to work as it is on that site. Can someone tell me if the code will work with python3.3??? 
http://flowingdata.com/2007/07/09/grabbing-weather-underground-data-with-beautifulsoup/

Comment: It works for me. How are you running this code?

Comment: file/open and open file which opens in a new shell.Then I run it.

Comment: Could you add `print(html)` and then `input("program done: hit enter")` to the end of your program?  Maybe it's simply set up to restart when a program ends.

Comment: you guys are brilliant. the new two lines worked. I don't understand where the restart is set.  How do I fix it or do I just use the new two lines in my codes going forward??

Answer (score 2):

I think I see what's probably going on.  You're likely using IDLE, and when it starts a new run of a program, it prints the

```
======RESTART=========
```

line to tell you that a fresh program is starting.  That means that all the variables currently defined are reset and/or deleted, as appropriate.

Since your program didn't print any output, you didn't see anything.

The two lines I suggested adding were just tests to figure out what was going on, they're not needed in general.  [Unless the window itself is automatically closing, which it shouldn't.]  But as a rule, if you want to see output, you'll have to `print` what you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works for me.  However, I suggest using requests instead of urllib2.

To simplify the example you linked to, it would look like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

resp = requests.get("http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KBUF/2007/12/16/DailyHistory.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text)
```